# Python Kivy: ValueError: Empty module name. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, import, kivy

I am trying to run a todo list program and this is the error I am receiving in Pycharm:

File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/lang.py", line 1085, in execute_directives
     mod = **import**('.'.join(package.split('.')[:-1]))
 ValueError: Empty module name

Process finished with exit code 1

Here is the code in main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton


class TaskButton(ListItemButton):
    pass


class TodoRoot(BoxLayout):
    task_input = ObjectProperty()
    task_list = ObjectProperty()

    def add_task(self):
        self.task_list.adapter.data.extend([self.task_input.text])
        self.task_list._trigger_reset_populate()

    def del_task(self, *args):
        if self.task_list.adapter.selection:
            selection = self.task_list.adapter.selection[0].text
            self.task_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)
            self.task_list._trigger_reset_populate()


class TodoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TodoRoot()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TodoApp().run()
```

Here is the code in todo.kv

```
#: import main todo
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton

TodoRoot:

<TodoRoot>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    task_input: task_input_view
    task_list: tasks_list_view

BoxLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "40dp"

    TextInput:
        id: task_input_view
        size_hint_x: 70
    Button:
        text: "Add"
        size_hint_x: 15
        on_press: root.add_task()
    Button:
        text: "Del"
        size_hint_x: 15
        on_press: root.del_task()
ListView:
    id: tasks_list_view
    adapter:
        ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.TaskButton)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are other issues with your code as it stands, but the import error you are getting seems to come from the

```
#: import main todo
```

If this is meant to import the main.py, Kivy already provides a way to reference structures from the main script into the .kv file using the "app" keyword (see [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords)). For example, in the last line of your .kv files,

```
ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.TaskButton)
```

could be replaced with

```
ListAdapter(data=[], cls=app.TaskButton)
```

The other issue, is that there can only be one root widget in the .kv file, and three are provided in your code: TodoRoot, BoxLayout and ListView. Only one widget can be defined as root (without the trailing "<>"). Perhaps there is an indentation problem, and all other widgets should be inside TodoRoot?